# In jQuery, should I put all my code in one .ready() event or multiple?

Tags: jquery, coding-style

I was wondering what would be the best programming practice for jQuery. Most jquery actions seem to need to be contained within the `.ready()` or else it doesn't work. If I have a bunch of actions that I want to code, I could put them all within one big `.ready()`. What I have been doing is creating a a new `.ready()` for each function since I felt that this would be the easiest way to copy and paste the function if I ever wanted to reuse it for another website. But I think this is going to get a bit out of hand. Any ideas?

Comment: document.ready is equivalent of onload

Comment: The title was a little vague and I assume that's why you were downvoted. I edited it to be more to the point and hopefully that will attract more positive attention.

Comment: @kobe The jQuery `.ready()` is more like the DOM `.DOMContentLoaded()` event. It's not at all the equivalent of `.onload`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+multiple+ready&submit=search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acess the HTML and CSS of a page over the document object model (short: DOM). jQuery simplifies accessing the DOM. When the page loads it also takes some time until the DOM is fully loaded and ready.

If you try to acess the DOM before it's ready, your code won't run properly. `$(document).ready()` executes a function when the DOM is ready and you can acess it properly.

You don't need several of those events. One function as an argument for the `$(document).ready()` is enoug.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Put all the code that needs the DOM to work in here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason code is written in .ready() is if code uses the DOM tree. In that case it should be executed after the DOM is loaded, which is either in document.ready or in script just before the end  tag. In order not to rely where the script tag is located, the code is executed on document ready.

As for your code, better put it in functions, and call the functions in document.ready, instead of putting the whole implementation there.

Without actual code, it's hard to give more advices.